# React Native Animated.sequence has lag between animations

Tags: react-native, animation, delay, lag

I have the issue when try to combine two animations with Animated.sequence. I  have a hardly visible lag (delay) between animations but it is critical for user experience in my app. This is clearly visible on the slow motion video record. In the example bellow is a simplified version my animation for demonstration this issue. In my example cursor moves for 800 ml sec then stops and then moves another 800 ml sec. How can I avoid stopping between animations?

```
export const TestAnimation = () => {
  const { Layout } = useTheme();
  let cursorPosition = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const firstAnimation = Animated.timing(cursorPosition, {
    toValue: 150,
    duration: 800,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  });
  const secondAnimation = Animated.timing(cursorPosition, {
    toValue: 300,
    duration: 800,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  });

  const combinedAnimation = Animated.sequence([
    firstAnimation,
    secondAnimation,
  ]);
  return (
    <View style={[Layout.fill, Layout.alignItemsCenter, Layout.relative]}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          Layout.absolute,
          Styles.cursor,
          {
            transform: [
              {
                translateX: cursorPosition,
              },
            ],
          },
        ]}
      />
      <Button
        title="Start Animation"
        onPress={() => {
          combinedAnimation.start();
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Reset Animation"
        onPress={() => {
          cursorPosition.setValue(0);
          combinedAnimation.reset();
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

This behavior is partially corrected by switching to `useNativeDriver: false`, but it gives other issues.